# Search results won't display from Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can not get the search results to display on the results page. I know its working because pagination and other features are working and displaying, I just can't get the actual search results (site title, url and desc) to display, need some fresh eyes(!) and ideas(?)

HTML element for directive:

```
<search-results ng-model="searchTerms" results="results.documents" site-urls="page.url" site-title="page.title" site-content="page.content"  uib-typeahead="query for query in getSuggestions($viewValue)" typeahead-on-select="search($item)"></search-results>
```

HTML template for directive:

```
    <div ng-repeat="page in results.documents" id="result-list-items">
<h3>
    <a href="{{page.url}}">
        <span id="results-list-title" ng-bind-html="page.title"></span>
    </a>
</h3>
<h4 class="list-group-item-heading" id="results-list-url" ng-bind-html="page.url"></h4>
<p class="list-group-item-text" id="results-list-desc" ng-bind-html="page.content"></p>
</div>
```

AngularJS for directive:

```
'use strict';

angular.module("searchengine.search-results", [])
    .directive('searchResults', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'search/search-results.html',
            controller: ['homeCtrl','searchCtrl'],
            scope: {
                searchTerms: "=",//ngModel
                results: "=",
                siteUrls: "=",
                siteTitle: "=",
                siteContent: "=",
                suggestions: "&",
                search: "&"
            }
            //link: {(scope, elem, attr)
            //}
        }
    });
```

Comment: what you try do here? `controller: ['homeCtrl','searchCtrl'],`?

Comment: @Grundy using the directive with both controllers, homeCtrol is basically just for autocomplete (suggestions)

Comment: this not work in his way, see [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-controller-)